# digital clock using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anybody has a suggestion on how to build a textbox that is exactly like the one showing the windows time using javascript and/or jquery?

Comment: You have a lot of unanswered questions. Please try to accept some answers from your previous questions first.

Comment: Very easy to do with some javascript and jQuery. As Prutswonder suggests, marking questions is important as it completes the loop and helps identify the best solution to the question.

Comment: thanks for the note, i marked the answers to my questions :)
but i really am interested in building a similar clock, so where do i begin?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main idea is to trigger an event each second or millisecond.
Which you can do using `setTimeout(1000, 'updateClockUI()');` in JavaScript.

in updateClockUI() you refresh your clock UI by updating the currently displayed time.
To get the current date/time and other useful functions regarding date/time in JavaScript see http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php

Find some examples here:
http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/07/7-wonderful-analog-and-digital-clocks-using-css-and-javascript/